# How mock the component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm new in reactJS. I test my component `RegisterForm` with `Jest`.

I'm mock components that are already tested (e.g. `PasswordField`). Therefore, i mock it but I have an error that appears:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Field`.

   9 | describe('HeaderContainer', () => {
  10 |     it('render correctly', ()=>{
> 11 |         const tree = renderer.create(
     |                               ^
  12 |            <RegisterForm />
  13 |         ).toJSON();
  14 |         expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
```

Do you know how I can solve the problem ?

this is my test:

```
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import React from "react";
import {RegisterForm} from "../../../../components/form";
import {PasswordField} from "../../../../components/textFields";


jest.mock('../../../../components/textFields', () => ('PasswordField'));

describe('HeaderContainer', () => {
    it('render correctly', ()=>{
        const tree = renderer.create(
           <RegisterForm />
        ).toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()

    })
});
```

Comment: Can you show us what `Field` component is?

Comment: the Field component belongs to the Formik component `<Field
                      name="firstName"
                      validate={value => this._validateFirstName(value)}
                    >
                      {({ meta }) => (<MyCustomerComponent)} </Field>`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the named import in your test not the default one. You probably need

```
import RegisterForm from "...."
```

If you have some HOC around the RegisterForm and you are actually trying to use a named export then you have to export the component as well as the default export (might look something like)

```
export const RegisterForm = (props) => {}; //named export
export default RegisterForm; //default export
```

The error that you posted is pointing you towards that - `or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`